# SQL Server : datetime comparison ignoring few milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I noticed that 2 datetimes are considered equal if one is

```
2010-12-31 15:13:48.000
```

and the other

```
2010-12-31 15:13:48.001.
```

I thought in the beginning that it was rounding up or down to nearest full seconds but it turned out

```
2010-12-31 15:13:48.002
```

registers the difference correctly.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 7):

The `datetime` data type is accurate to 3 milliseconds (0.0033 seconds), so your results make sense.  Values are *rounded* to 0.000, 0.003, and 0.007.  So, your first example is rounded to: "2010-12-31 15:13:48.000" and the second to "2010-12-31 15:13:48.003".

You can read about this in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Yes totally right. You can see this too here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: I would add that datetime2 is extreamly more accurate (100 nanoseconds), so if milliseconds are needed, datetime2 is the datatype to choose.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores datetimes to the precision of 1/300 of a second (~3.33 milliseconds), as [stated by the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx):

> ate and time data from January 1, 1753 through December 31, 9999, to an accuracy of one three-hundredth of a second (equivalent to 3.33 milliseconds or 0.00333 seconds). Values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the table.

So depending on where exactly the rounding occurs, timestamps that differ by up to three milliseconds may be considered equal.